# Does the Xcode provide the iCal in the simulator?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I want to ask a question about the iPhone application. I use the Xcode to write the iPhone application about the calendar and the simulator is 3.1.3.

However, I cannot see the Calendar app. (The simulator only displays the 1. Photos and 2. Settings). Do I need to set something or download from the Internet in order to see the Calendar app? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunatelly the iPhone simulator does not come with the calendar app. However you can still store and retrieve data from the calendar database, which is part of the system databases and will be stored at the `iOSUserDomain`. See [Using iPhone Simulator](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iPhone_Simulator/iphone_simulator_application.html) for more info.

Comment: thank you for your reply. And I want to ask that are there some pre-defined events within the iPhone simulator?

Comment: I guess you mean calendar events.. 

There are no predefined calendar events. But you can check yourself by opening the iPhone simulator's sqlite database. It should be located at: /Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/Library/Calendar/Calendar.sqlitedb

Answer (score 4):

Even though this question is old, I found myself asking it last week and solved my issues by running the simple sample app for EKEventKitUI. It let me add events in the calendar db and see the events my app was adding/editing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier, iPhone simulator does not come with the Calendar app.

The data is still stored at the calendar database which should be located at something like:

> /Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/3.1.3/Library/Calendar/Calendar.sqlitedb

But this is an encrypted file and cannot be opened with an sqlite DB application like MesaSQLite.

A simple hack seems to be to run the sample app for the EKEventKitUI framework from the iOS Developer Library and use it to see (and edit) the events list.
Current link to download it is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html).

N.B. this is a consolidated answer from various other answers found on SO and outside. Credit to everyone else who answers I drew on for this.