# How to load iphone calendar application in iphone simulator 4.0

Tags: iphone

How to load iphone calendar application in iphone simulator 4.0 ?

Is it possible ?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer - it is not possible.

The simulator doesn't come with the Calendar.app. Simulator is able to run only applications that are compiled for Intel processor. So even if you could somehow get the Calendar app from the iPhone, it would not run as it is compiled for ARM cpu.

Answer (score 5):

While there is no calendar app in the simulator the entries are stored in a sqlite database in $HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator//Library/Calendar/Calendar.sqlitedb

Calendar Events are stored in several tables but mainly in a table called CalendarItem which can be opened with a sqlite viewer.

If you need a very easy sql lite viewer the FireFox plugin SQLite Manager works like a champ.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, there is NO calendar app on the simulator, 
but the sqlite db is available at

> /Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator//Library/Calendar/Calendar.sqlitedb

if you can't seem to open that sqlite db, check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608993/2147976